# Секундомер на Си (Linux)

Tags: c, slackware

*Разработать программу, имитирующую работу цифрового секундомера, который позволяет измерять временные интервалы с точностью до миллисекунды. Временной интервал должен измеряться от момента запуска программы до момента интерактивного прерывания ее работы по сигналу от клавиатуры. Изменение времени в пределах измеряемого интервала должно отображаться в одной строке потока стандартного вывода (stdout). Формат вывода должен содержать поля для отображения часов, минут и секунд, разделенные символом двоеточия, а также поле для отображения миллисекунд, которое отделяется от поля секунд символом точки. Обновление информации в полях указанного формата должно происходить с периодичностью одна миллисекунда. При этом модифицироваться должны только те цифры строки вывода, значения которых изменились относительно предыдущего отображаемого момента времени.*

1)Как сделать модификацию только изменившейся цифры ? Да и вообще строки в целом (\r не вариант, обновляет всю строку)
2)Как в этом случае сделать остановку по нажатию на клавишу (Не ctrl+C желательно)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int start, end;
    int ms= 0;
    int ns= 0;
    int sec=0 , min=0 , hrs=0;
    start = clock ();
    while (1)
    {
        end = clock ();
        ns= end - start;
        ms = ns / 10;
        if (ms>100)
        {
            sec = sec + 1; 
            ms= ms - 100;
            start= end;
        }
        if (sec > 59)
        {
            min = min+1;
            sec= 0;
        }
        if (min > 59)
        {
            hrs = hrs + 1;
            min=0;
        }
        printf ("%d:%d:%d.%d\n",hrs, min, sec, ms );
    }
}
```

Comment: Создай еще один поток и в нем уже обработай нажатие клавиш.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вариант - либо использовать `\r` и выводить новую строку поверх старой (тем самым **выглядеть** цифры будут как не измененные...), либо (раз вам этот вариант не подходит)

использовать "забой" на нужное количество символов и выводить только изменившиеся цифры.

Я бы записывал все в строку, которую хранил. После этого сравнивал бы две строки, и смотрел, где начинается отличие.

С клавишами - если у вас в системе есть тот же `<conio.h>`, то проверять в том же цикле, не была ли нажата клавиша, и если была - то какая...

Comment: Я бы этот код запускал в потоке, а в основном ожидал `getchar();`, при прохождении символа убивал бы поток.. как то так

Comment: @NewView Тоже вариант.

Comment: @Harry Можно поконкретнее о каком "забое" идет речь, и как реализовать это

Comment: Символ backspace. Он же `\b`.

Comment: @NewView поконкретнее можно, как это реализовать ?

Comment: Можно конечно и  поконкретнее,  поищите в поиске `pthread_create` - вот через него и создайте поток, примеров полно.